# Running multiple operating systems on one machine

Tags: linux, boot, operating-systems

I want to run different operating systems on one machine. I have Windows 10 already installed and I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I made some research and I know that I have a couple of options.

1. Using a virtual machine (not an option for me)

I don't want to use this option because you can't do whatever you want with a virtual machine. For example, you can't play games or do graphics related things. There are some other limitations also

https://www.pcworld.com/article/2050345/understand-the-limits-of-a-virtual-computer.html

2. Dual boot on the same disk (not an option for me)

I don't want to use this option because there are some problems with this solution. Sometimes Windows updates changes loader and this may cause that I will have to repair and reinstall a lot of things in order to be able to use Linux. Another issue is related to time management. It also sometimes creates problems.
I found a good video about problems with dual booting
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9iX2qSfMhE

3. Dual boot on different disks

I think this is the best solution for me. But I am not sure 100%.
Suppose that I have Windows on disk1 and Linux on disk2. Where I can hold my data? I always have a system on one disk and the data on the other. Because the system may crash and I don't want to lose my data.

I always have a copy on external disk but I do this copy once a month so still I might lose some data in case of system crash if this data will be on the same disk as a system.

But on the other hand with two different systems, it is very unlikely that both of these systems will crash. So in case of Windows system failure, I can still log into Linux and I can see the content of the disk on which Windows is. Is it true or not?
Can I see the content of both disks after login into Windows and Linux?

I also consider using SteamOS. I am just curious about how it works. But this is not a priority.

I know that some of you may write "Just use Linux and not Windows". But I have some reasons to use Windows. I don't feel comfortable yet with Linux. But there is another more important reason - playing games. I am not a pro gamer but I like to play games from time to time. 
And even if Windows is the worst operating system in almost every aspect, there is one thing that is most developed on Windows - just games.

So what do you recommend for me? Is it a good solution to install two systems on two disks? And do I need GRUB software to be able to use this? Or just my boot menu is enough? I haven't checked the installation guide yet. And what with SteamOS? Should I use an external drive? Or is it safe to dual boot on the same disk if both systems are Linux or both systems are Windows?

Is this video true if you want to have two or more Linux systems or Windows systems?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9iX2qSfMhE

My laptop specification:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDBNi.png)

Comment: Why just not to install linux subsistem for windows and practicing with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Kacper777 As per your FIRST  questions**

> I don't want to use this option because you can't do whatever you want with a **virtual machine. For example, you can't play games or do graphics** related things. There are some other limitations also

I dont think there are much 3D heavey graphics  Games or heavy graphics designing  softwares for Linux or ubuntu

common things to be kept in mind are virtualisation is not a full blown OS as its never a native piece of software working on a machine its always semi native or virtual as the name suggests, so it’s better to go for a live CD or DVD or install on your HDD… and dual boot them. Vmware is good for just testing purposes, if you really need to dive deep in then it is necessary to install or say dual boot Linux into a separate partition say ext4 or zfs with swap files and all.

still you can see following  links and discussions on limitations and  problems of ubuntu in virtual machine. The only  problems come with virtualisations with devices and peripheral devices  like printers dont work Most likely, printers, graphics tablets and other peripherals won't work at all.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121951/better-vm-ubuntu-on-windows-10-or-vm-windows-10-on-ubuntu

https://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox

https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_performance_difference_between_Virtual_System_and_Physical_System

https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/dual-booting-vs-virtual-machine/

**Kacper777 As per your SECOND  questions**

> Sometimes **Windows updates changes loader and this may cause that I will have to repair and reinstall** a lot of things in order to be able to use Linux. Another issue is related to time management. It also sometimes creates problems.

**Every problems have solutions. NO PAINS NO GAINS.** so tricks and see links below to how  to  solve the problems

sharing some links to understand the problem and details

https://askubuntu.com/questions/937799/lost-dual-boot-on-windows-update

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/how-can-i-prevent-windows-from-overwriting-grub-when-using-a-dual-boot-machine

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-anniversary-update-destroys-boot-loader/93d60fa6-b856-4714-a85a-861b780b9986

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-update-delete-linux/

**TIME MANAGEMENT LINKS**

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/time-differences-ubuntu-1604-windows-10/

https://www.howtogeek.com/323390/how-to-fix-windows-and-linux-showing-different-times-when-dual-booting/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/700734/windows-10-and-ubuntu-14-04-lts-dual-booting-issues

**GUIDES FOR DUAL BOOTINGS**

https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-alongside-with-windows-dual-boot/

https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10/

https://dev.to/praveenjm2000/making-it-simple-dual-booting-ubuntu-with-windows-10-for-absolute-biginners-2faj

**Kacper777 As per your THIRD  questions**

> Where **I can hold my data?** I always have a s**ystem on one disk and the data on the other**. Because the system may crash and I don't want to lose my data.

You can save  data on a partition of second or first disk you wish and create a partition for  backing up image or shadow or mirror of first disk. Keep OS in one disk. Before installing linux its advisable to create a image file of your HDD and data disk.

again sharing links for  data corruption as linux is must stable but in once in 1000 there may be chance for corruption due to different file system support of linux and windows.

Many videos and  users say there MAY  be chance they  dont say  there should be 100% chance of corruption Still it always better to create an backup image or cloud backup of your data  for safety

Corruption Crashes solutions tricks and advice's in other discussions you  can  read which my be helpful for your knowledge

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085989/possible-corrupt-ntfs-system-windows-files-still-accessible-via-ubuntu

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1709302

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/risks-dual-booting-windows-linux-operating-systems/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412990/how-could-windows-not-corrupt-the-linux-file-system-when-messing-up-partition-sc

[Hard drive corruption on a dual-boot system](https://superuser.com/questions/1041095/hard-drive-corruption-on-a-dual-boot-system)

https://www.quora.com/Does-my-Windows-get-affected-if-I-messed-up-in-Linux-while-dual-booting

https://www.quora.com/If-I-install-Ubuntu-on-my-computer-will-it-erase-my-current-operating-system

**Kacper777 As per your FOURTH ADVICE AND SUGGESTION REQUEST questions**

> So **what do you recommend for me?** Is it a good solution to install two systems on two disks?

firstly  its advisable better to keep OS in 1 disk  and   windows 10 in one partition and  linux on other partition and data on other disk for safety and corruption and file system protections which will protect your data and from any hard

secondly its advisable if you have space then create 2 partitions  in 1 partition keep the  data and second partitions keep the IMAGE file ie. backup of both bootable system HDD and data HDD for your safety ...and if possible keep those images copies in DVD drive or Blue ray disk or  on cloud  for safety of any HDD or system boot failure

**As per my  thoughts experience and knowledge**, I am to **novice and new to linux** and was finding solution to **learn linux** I **have not used Ubuntu** and  want to install on my PC and laptop and my question was same  and i founded a best solution  for my self may be it suits you to.

The solution i founded is  to install Linux on Flash pen drive  have not tried and dont know about its pros or cons and problems but think it best suits your problems.

As it will **benefit you in following  ways** :-

1. No need  To install Linux in Dual boot with current OS in your first HDD where your windows 10 is installed
2. It will also  not effect your second HDD with data saved
3. It will also  not effect you to play games in windows
4. It will also not corrupt any file system or  booting files or boot menus GRUB UEFI or any other files.
5. It will also not take any space in your laptop or  HDD.
6. You can also  boot in  VM and directly from  USB flash drive laptop also
7. You can move with your flash pen drive at any place other Desktop or Laptop  and carry your linux OS in your  pocket at any place
8. **Install Ubuntu  or linux OS in Flash drive or USB pen drive or External USB HDD SSD** and whenever wherever needed Just boot from flash drive  and this will not effect your  Windows 10 OS or attach or detach  your
9. Now **How to install Linux Ubuntu in Flash drive** or pen drive or  **External HDD** is a big topic so below  is the VIDEOS and link  i am sharing   it below see it may help you

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIhYitXwJfE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLYBXOVn6ow

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/install-real-ubuntu-os-usb-drive/

https://www.cnet.com/how-to/what-to-do-with-your-usb-flash-drive-run-linux/

https://www.dionysopoulos.me/portable-ubuntu-on-usb-hdd/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119700/how-to-fully-install-ubuntu-on-usb-flashdrive

> Hope **above tips and suggestions and links**  **helped you**   if any of them **worked and suited** you do **tell me in comments** which one worked for you for my knowledge and if **not suited** or helped you then **feel free to ask any  doubts** for **further clarifications** and if worked then D**ONT FORGET to vote and accept the answer**

Comment: Thank you, great answer! I will test your tips. One more thing. These are my disks. http://www.zapisz.net/imagesnew/2020/03/26/0f4d2905a475c771cc2c700d105e8c98.png On C I have Windows and this is SSD and it is not that capacious. On D I have my data, programs, videos, films, and the majority of games. And Seagate is an external hard drive and it has almost the same things as disk D because this is a copy. I think this a terrible waste of space. I don't know what is shadow/mirror of the disk but I will check it.

Comment: But my question now is: how to organize this? Maybe I should move the Windows system on the disk D. And Linux would be on smaller disk, Windows on bigger disk on a separate partition and games and other data on another partition. I know that games like SSD but with this machine is not that a difference in performance. And games take a lot of space. But I have a question. Suppose that I am already logged into the Linux system. Can I use my data from a second bigger disk on Linux? Is it possible to have access to data from both systems?

Answer (score 4):

> Sometimes Windows updates changes loader and this may cause that I will have to repair and reinstall a lot of things in order to be able to use Linux.

This is a non-issue if you're using UEFI boot (and unless you've installed Windows in CSM boot mode, you are - it's been a default for 10 or so years now). With UEFI boot Windows's and Linux's loaders live in their own directories on EFI System Partition (ESP) and don't overwrite each other. The worst that can happen is your boot order can be changed to default to Windows. You can easily change it back in UEFI setup. You can also choose to boot non-default OS (ie. Linux) once and use `efibootmgr` to change boot order.

> Where I can hold my data? I always have a system on one disk and the data on the other. Because the system may crash and I don't want to lose my data.

This is also a non-issue. A "crash" will ruin OS partition at most. Keep your data on a separate partition and you're done.

It's great that you have backups. Disks fail, sometimes without warning. Without backups it's just a matter of time until you lose something - either due to random hardware failure, power spike, software failure, ransomware or accidental deletion. So good job. **But!** A manual copy is not a proper backup. First, it should be automated - less effort = less friction, you can backup more often. Second, it should be incremental, ie. only differences between current snapshot and previous one are recorded, this way you can restore to any point in time (useful for accidental file deletion) and you don't waste space for duplicates, so even weekly backups become feasible.

If you want to transfer data between OSes, you'll need a filesystem that works well on both systems. NTFS has pretty decent support on Linux. exFAT seems to work well too, but I didn't use it much. Remember to disable fast startup in Windows, otherwise it will hibernate on poweroff and hibernated partitions can't be accessed safely in other OS.

SteamOS isn't designed to be installed in dual boot. If you're new to this, I would advise against it.

My recommendation for a Linux newcomer would be: play games on Windows, learn Linux in a VM. This solves all your problems.

Comment: I want to learn Linux, but I also want Linux to increase my productivity. Because Linux is more reliable and has a lot of great features. I saw the feature of workspaces on Linux and it is much better than virtual desktops on Windows. I am planning to use Ubuntu with the KDE desktop environment. I would like to have real Linux, not VM. Virtual machines have a lot of limitations, not only speed.

Comment: @Kacper777 Linux isn't objectively superior to Windows, despite what some people claim. Speed may not be a concern at all, modern CPUs can run VMs with almost no overhead thanks to hardware virtualization features like VT-x or AMD-V. Graphics performance will be slightly degraded in most setups, but it's usually satisfactory thanks to paravirtualization. What other limitations are you worried about?

Comment: Things described in the first link                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "If a machine doesn't exist in the real world, it can't possibly have any USB ports, making it difficult to plug in a flash drive.

Comment: You can, of course, plug the drive into the real computer. But then the host takes control of the drive. It takes a couple of steps and some waiting to "connect" the drive to the VM. That doesn't always work, either."

Comment: "It will always be slower, have less physical RAM, worse graphics, and fewer gigabytes of storage."                                                                                                                                      I have been using a virtual machine (VirtualBox) for a few months. And when I have a lot of programs running at the same I have lags sometimes. And the system is not working so fast and smoothly like normal Windows which is not in VM.

Comment: Usually, I have about 20 tabs in Google Chrome opened, text editor or IDE (JetBrains products, Visual Studio Code and so on), maybe some videos that I download from youtube. And I am planning to do some machine learning and this requires a lot of power.                                                                                                              I don't know why there is such limitation of characters in comments

Comment: A-ok, spaces used to make the new line, haha